# Multiple foreach loops statements

Tags: php, mysql, loops, codeigniter, foreach

How do I handle using multiple `foreach` loops? However, **it gives 16 rows when only it should give 4** - since it repeats the entries  many times over. In few words, I  read from MySQL all subcategories and mark which have been previously checked by checkbox and then update all.

What am I doing wrong here - any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Currently I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xm-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" role="grid">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php $valuesub = ($page->subcat_recip_id);
                        $array_of_values = explode(",", $valuesub);

                        foreach ($menu_links as $item):

                        if ($item['parent_id'] != "0" && $item['subcat_recip_id'] == "0"):?>
                        <?php foreach($array_of_values as $dt):  ?>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="subcat_recip_id" class="square-purple"
                               value="<?php echo html_escape($item["title"]); ?>" <?=(in_array($dt, $item)) ? "CHECKED" : ""?>> <?=html_escape($item["title"]);  ?>
                        &nbsp;
                        <?php  endforeach;endif;endforeach; ?>

                    </td><?php echo html_escape($valuesub); ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An example array `$array_of_values` contains:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "Appetizers" [1]=> string(9) "Beverages" [2]=> string(7) "Dessert" [3]=> string(5) "Bread" }
```

Comment: you are iterating $menu_links instead of $array_of_values

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Pls what should I change to iterating $array_of_values ?

Comment: could you show what this `$menu_links` contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aboot $dt must be loop in input checkbox,
look this code:

```
<td> 
<?php foreach ($menu_links as $item) :
$valuesub = explode(",",$page->subcat_recip_id); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat_recip_id[]" class="square-purple" value="<?php echo html_escape($item["title"]); ?>" <?php foreach($valuesub as $dt): echo ($dt==$item['title'])?"CHECKED":""; endforeach;?> > <?=html_escape($item["title"]);?>&nbsp;
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</td>
```

thanks

Comment: How!! Great, Thank you.